# How to convert "org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord" to "java.util.Map"?

Tags: java, avro, avro-tools

Easy way to convert "org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord" to "java.util.Map"

Answer (score 6):

With java 8 lambdas you can do this like

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
genericRecord.getSchema().getFields().forEach(field -> 
    map.put(field.name(), genericRecord.get(field.name())));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 Map<String, Object> values = new HashMap<>();
 for (Field field : genericRecord.getSchema().getFields()) {
    values.put(field.name(), genericRecord.get(field.name()));
 }
```

Comment: This code snippet doesnt seem to handle the field of type Record !!!